# Firefox Filechooser Dialogs don't have a select/save button in Loki

Tags: gtk, firefox, release-loki

I'm currently trying out Loki, and it's running quite fine as far as I see. Only real annoyance: Firefox is currently showing a bug. 
If I open a Filechooser in Firefox, no matter if its for saving a page, uploading a file to a site,etc...nothing can be selected. You can browse all folders, navigate through them, highlight an entry, but the options to select an entry are missing. Literally: there is no OK Button.

Any others experiencing this?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader':<0>}"
```

It's fixed and should arrive soon.